# mutate_if() with OR conditions dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

If I want to convert an `integer` or `double` variables to `character` variables,
how can I accomplish the task, I tried the below code, but I am certain this is an incorrect way.

```
storms %>% mutate_if(c(is.integer | is.double),
                     .funs = as.character)
```

Comment: You can use a custom function as the predicate, such as one that returns true for either of those conditions. Beyond that, you probably want a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this version of `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
storms %>% mutate_if(~ is.double(.) | is.integer(.), as.character)
```

which would convert the double or integer columns to character.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `base R`

```
storms[] <- lapply(storms, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) as.character(x) else x)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(storms)[, names(storms) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
        if(is.numeric(x)) as.character(x) else x)]
```